# sorting array of tuples in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

Is there a way to sort an array of tuple in matlab . Let's say there is a tuple of type (datatype1,datatype2,datatype3) and I want to sort an array of tuples using first index and then if there is any conflict then it is resolved using the second index and so on .

Comment: What are _tuples_ in matlab ?

Answer (score 2):

[`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) does exactly that. You apply it to a matrix, where each row is a tuple:

```
>> A = [1 2 3;
        2 0 4;
        1 4 1;
        1 2 1]; %// example data

>> sorted_A = sortrows(A);
sorted_A =
     1     2     1
     1     2     3
     1     4     1
     2     0     4
```

You can specify the "priority" of the columns for sorting (default is: first column, then second etc); and for each column whether you want ascending or descending order (default is ascending).